# How to hardcode a Unique Serial Number to Each ESP32 in a production line?

Tags: arduino, embedded, esp32, arduino-esp32, esp-idf

How can we flash a Unique Serial Number to a large amount of ESP32s that are already, flashed with the Main Code?

How can this be done, if people on production line shouldn't be given access or permission to modify the Original Source Code.

I would appreciate any ideas or innovative solutions to this.

I have figured out that we need to use the NVS(Non Volatile Storage) to store the Custom Serial Number, but is there any good way to give the employees in the production line direct secure one time access to NVS without the need for re-flashing the original code that needs to be secure.

Thank You.

Comment: Note, the esp32 has a unique mac address which could be used to derive a serial number without needing to modify anything. See the discussion around [esp_efuse_mac_get_default()](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/misc_system_api.html#mac-address).

Answer (score 0):

Generically, i.e not ESP32 specific, you could build the means to program the serial number in NVS into your application itself where all necessary security and constraints may be applied without giving control of the entire NVS to the external system. That function might then be triggered by command over the serial interface for example.

If the serial number is already programmed, the command can be ignored, making it a "one-time" operation.  You might have a "secret" magic serial number, to allow clearing/resetting the serial number for production rework for example.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Understood the approach. Will research more on this.